# java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.nz.bird.model.Bird

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a issue returning spring entity.

The error is:

```
ava.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.nz.bird.model.Bird (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.nz.bird.model.Bird is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @2ac3eaff)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.findmyBird(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

My bird class:

```
@Entity
@Data

public class Bird {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Name must not be null or empty")
    private String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Sex sex;
    // some other fields

    // empty constructor
    // all fields constructor

    // getters & setters
```

The repository looks like:

```
@Query("SELECT b.name, b.sex FROM Bird b WHERE b.id = 1")
Bird findmyBird();
```

I get that its a cast exception, but why is Hibernate not converting the returned strings to POJOs - and the resulting error?

**UDPATE**

Returning a bird entity with:

```
    @Query("SELECT b FROM Bird b WHERE b.id = 1")
    Bird findmyBird();
```

Work.

**UPDATE**

Trying to run this on the same repo does not:

```
public interface BirdRepository extends JpaRepository<Bird, Long> {
@Query(name = "find_bird_full", nativeQuery = true)
BirdDTO getBirdDTO(@Param("id")Long id);

@Query("SELECT new com.nz.bird.dto.BirdTestDTO(b.name, b.sex) FROM Bird b WHERE b.id = 1")
BirdTestDTO findmyBird();
```

Note the second query where it is defined the return type.

The error is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'birdServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\AlGrant\IdeaProjects\bird\build\classes\java\main\com\nz\kiwi\implementation\BirdServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'birdRepository' defined in com.nz.bird.repository.BirdRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.nz.bird.dto.BirdTestDTO com.nz.bird.repository.BirdRepository.findmyBird()! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.nz.bird.dto.BirdTestDTO com.nz.bird.repository.BirdRepository.findmyBird()!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.nz.bird.dto.BirdTestDTO com.nz.bird.repository.BirdRepository.findmyBird()!
```

I would like to get the other method mentioned in the comments to also work.

Comment: Because you wrote a query that returns 2 arbitrary columns. If you would do `SELECT b FROM Bird b WHERE b.id = 1` it would work.

Comment: So is there not a way query just what you need and return it to a DTO directly or a entity but only with selected fields?

Comment: @M.Deinum would orm.xml allow me to write queries which I can then mao to DTO for a seamless way to get entity direct to DTO?

Comment: you can refer to how Spring Projections work and use a similar approach. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Comment: JPA supports that out-of-the-box (I would suggest a read on how JPA works). But if you create a DTO that has a constructor for your fields you can do something like `SELECT new your.package.to.YourDto(b.name, b.sex) FROM Bird b WHERE b.id =1` Which will create your dto. With Spring Data JPA you can use a projection to make it a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

as M. Deinum said you must use "select b from Bird b where b.id = 1"
but if you want to create a dto and fill some of the properties only, you can use the code below:

```
@Autowired
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

in your method:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(queryStr, params, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Dto.class));
```

where params is a Map<String, Object> and replace Dto.class with your dto.

note that it returns a list of converted dto, but if you want single object use the code below:

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(queryStr, params, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Dto.class));
```

and also you can implement these codes as generics to use anywhere

Comment: What he wants is supported by JPA out of the box, no need to switch to jdbc template for that.

Comment: Exactly true, I forgot to mention him to use projection instead

Comment: So how would this be done with project (or I presume orm.xml?) - link to concrete example anywhere?

Comment: you can see jpa projection with code snippet here: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/